# Как реализовать IComparer<T> для сравнения нескольких свойств?

Tags: c#, .net

Положим, есть следуюший класс:

```
class Operation
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public int Baz { get; set; }
}
```

Я хочу реализовать компарер `IComparer<T>`. Код получается такой:

```
class OperationComparer : IComparer<Operation>
{
    public int Compare(Operation x, Operation y)
    {
        if (x.Foo == y.Foo && x.Bar == y.Bar && x.Baz == y.Baz)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1; // ???
    }
}
```

Однако непонятно, что возвращать, если свойства не равны. Когда возвращать 1, а когда −1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Общий порядок написания компарера следующий:

1. Сравнить первое свойство, по которому происходит сравнение (сортировка), получив −1/0/1 (меньше/равно/больше).
2. Если свойства не равны, вернуть −1 или 1 в соответствии с результатом сравнения. Для изменения порядка сортировки вернуть противоположное число.
3. Если свойства равны, перейти к пункту 1 со следующим свойством. Если свойства кончились, вернуть результат последнего сравнения как есть.

Код получается следующий:

```
class OperationComparer : IComparer<Operation>
{
    public int Compare(Operation x, Operation y)
    {
        int cmp = string.Compare(x.Foo, y.Foo);
        if (cmp != 0)
            return cmp;
        cmp = string.Compare(x.Bar, y.Bar);
        if (cmp != 0)
            return cmp;
        cmp = x.Baz.CompareTo(x.Baz);
        return cmp;
    }
}
```

Стоит отметить, что в современном коде подобные компареры обычно не нужны, так как есть LINQ, в котором с помощью методов `OrderBy` и `ThenBy` ту же логику можно выразить гораздо проще.

Comment: может стоило однообразно сделать `x.Bar.CompareTo(y.Bar)` вместо `string.Compare(x.Bar, y.Bar)`?

Comment: а для анонимных типов как? например, есть `var arr = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(v => new { Id = v, Value = Value = DateTime.Now.Ticks });`

Comment: @Grundy Если строки могут быть null, то ваша версия свалится с NRE.

Comment: @Discord, логично

Comment: @Stack, а что для анонимных типов?

Comment: @Stack Никак. Вы не можете реализовать интерфейс с анонимным типом в качестве дженерикового параметра. Создайте неанонимный тип.

Comment: @Discord, ну вообще с помощью функций и инстанса анонимного типа можно, если при этом `class OperationComparer<T> : IComparer<T>`, но, конечно, доступа к полям класса T уже не будет внутри функции Compare, Но тут на помощь могут прийти рефлексия или dynamic

Comment: @Grundy Уговорили, переформулирую: нет *нормального* способа реализовать компарер для анонимного типа. :)

Comment: @Discord, Это да :-D